# Any Ideas how show two (or more) nearby polylines

Tags: leaflet

I ran into a problem when two nearby polylines merge visually.
It looks pretty when zoom is large.
[image]

And polylines are merged visually in one line with color mixing when zoom level is small.
[image]

I have an idea: polylines must render on a distance between them when zoom level is small and decrease the distance when zoom in.

Does anyone have experience with it?

Comment: https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset (from https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html )

Comment: Yes! It looks like what I need. Thank you.